# Laravel incrementing the db value by 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is function that is returning the view

```
    // show individual post
public function showPost($id){
    $targetPost = Post::findorFail($id);
    $targetPost->increment('post_view_count');
    $post = [
        'post' => $targetPost,
        'related_posts' => Post::all()->sortByDesc("id")->take(2)// load some related posts too
    ];
    return view('post_single', $post);
}
```

What I am wanting here is to update the value by 1 when someone visits the page, the posts are in a list view to some other page, user are supposed to click that link.
Everything is working, but instead of incrementing the value by 1, it is incrementing by 2 even if I hit the **reload** button.
What I can assume is that the page is ***requested twice or loading via some kinda middleware first. That's why the request is being sent twice***. How do I fix this?

Comment: try this: Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_view_count',1);

Comment: i recommend you  check your telescope or db profiler for multi query

Comment: This clearly shows that such basic counters are completely useless as source of statistics (or any other information but counter value)

Comment: `Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_view_count',1)` does the same, the page is requested twice, I can assume.

Comment: Have you solved? I have the same problem, I'm afraid it's due to some package

Comment: I've solved, in my case, I had an error in the css where the empty url method ("background-image: url()") caused the page itself to be called from browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a basic counter will not suit your needs. What you can do is create a migration for your Post Views:

```
Schema::create("post_views", function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->unsignedInteger("id");
        $table->unsignedInteger("id_post");
        $table->string("session_id");
        $table->string("user_id");
        $table->string("ip");
        $table->string("agent");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Next create a model that will handle the views for you

```
class PostsViews extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'posts_views';

public static function createViewLog($post) {
        $postsViews= new PostsViews();
        $postsViews->id_post = $post->id;
        $postsViews->titleslug = $post->titleslug;
        $postsViews->url = \Request::url();
        $postsViews->session_id = \Request::getSession()->getId();
        $postsViews->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $postsViews->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
        $postsViews->agent = \Request::header('User-Agent');
        $postsViews->save();
}
```

Now use this in your showPost function():

```
public function showPost($id){
$targetPost = Post::findorFail($id);
PostsViews::createViewLog($targetPost);
$post = [
    'post' => $targetPost,
    'related_posts' => Post::all()->sortByDesc("id")->take(2)
    ];
    return view('post_single', $post);
}
```

Now it will log all views but you can filter it out when you need it on User agent, IP address or session. You can also use that kind of filter when logging a view to just log 1 view per post per viewer.

Comment: I don't wanna keep the log of the views, I want a simple view table updated with each load. Unfortunately the page is requested twice on a single load.